# How to list user by discord bot

Tags: discord, discord.js

I want to know how to show all user that join discord channel by discord bot
.
.
.
(I know a little about discord.js & discord API)

Comment: Show us the code you've written so far. Here is the discord.js docs: https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/general/welcome

Comment: Sorry i haven't written that section yet. Because i don't know how to do or any concept. and thank you for docs but i'm so confused it. Do you have any example.

Comment: The code is relevant. I'm sure you've written how the bot goes online. Knowing how you named your variables is needed. Any code is better than no code.

Comment: It's true too. I'll try this. Thank you for suggest If i have any problem i will post later.

Answer (score 1):

```js
bot.on('message', message => {
const listedUsers = []; 
message.guild.channels.forEach(user => { 
message.channel.send(message.author.username)
}
message.channel.send(listedUsers)
}
```

I realise this will send every user in a channel in a lot of messages - but I hope this works